# Automate android project on google play console

Tags: android, automation, continuous-integration, google-play, google-play-console

Is there plugin or an API that support creating new project and upload first apk dynamic on google play console?

For apk updates we are using `com.github.triplet.play`

```
play {
    track = 'production'
    serviceAccountEmail = 'info'
    serviceAccountCredentials = file('info')
}
```

and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fastlane for release and build
Here is the link: https://docs.fastlane.tools/

It is open-sourced by Google itself and many developers are using it. It is a kind of CI/CD for Mobile Application Developers.

Comment: Is'nt fastlane only for updating project if you already have existence project on google console ?

Comment: As i read you just need initial authentication from google then you can create new production build, upload apk, upload meta data https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/release-deployment/